# VS Code doesn't auto-open the class attribute in .php files

Tags: php, html, macos, visual-studio-code, autocomplete

I'll try to explain my issue:
If I start to type class inside a tag and press return or tab key to trigger the suggestion it doesn't auto-open the class attribute, while in other files type it does.

I hope I have explained myself!

[image]

Comment: Can you please upload you image ?

Comment: I’ve already attached a gif that show the problem. Did you see it?

Comment: it seems like link is broken.

Comment: Try this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QbixV.gif